# Route config trims all the params in the get request

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, routeconfig

I have a route config in MVC project:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Client",
                url: "Client/{webUi}/{lang}/{*controllerUrl}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Client",
                    action = "Index",
                    lang = "en-GB"
                }
            );
```

I have a ClientController with method Index().

```
public ActionResult Index(string webUi, string lang, string controllerUrl)
        { ... }
```

I am trying to use URL:

```
Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles?from=bundle
```

However, when I am debugging the ClientController, I am getting that the value in controllerUrl is ImportBundles. The parameters from=bundle is just stripped away.

Is it possible to achieve?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

1. I just tried to use this URL:

   Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles/from/bundle

And it worked. But is it possible to use this format:

```
Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles?from=bundle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can access everything after the `?` inside your Action by accessing `Request.QueryString`.

```
Request.QueryString["from"] //would evaulate to "bundle"
```

You don't need the * for the catch-all in route definition to do that. If your format will always be `Client/ZWS/{lang}/ImportBundles?from=bundle`, you can get rid of it at the end of your route definition

```
...
url: "Client/{webUi}/{lang}/{controllerUrl}",
```

and `controllerUrl` will still evaluate to "ImportBundles"